# Is there a way to configure CosmosDB to use both the SQL (DocumentDB) and MongoDB APIs?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-powershell, azure-cli

When I create a new CosmosDB database in the Azure Portal, I have to choose between the various APIs (Gremlin, MongoDB, SQL/DocumentDB, and Table.)

As with soo many other limitations of the Azure Portal, I'm hoping that there is a way to configure the new CosmosDB to use multiple APIs using PowerShell or the Azuzre cli.

Is there a way to add additional APIs to my CosmosDB instance?  If not, will there be a way to do this in the future?

**Update:**
I just created a Cosmos DB Account with the Mongo api, and noticed that the Query Explorer is still available, and allows me to type in and execute SQL/DocumentDB queries, so apparently the default is to allow both APIs (Mongo and SQL/DocumentDB).  However, I'm not sure of how to get the ConnectionString (AccountKey) so that I can use the DocumentDB/SQL API the way the azure portal does in my own client. Anyone have ideas on how to setup the connection string from a CosmosDB using the Mongo API so that it is a valid connection string for the DocumentDB/Sql API?

Comment: What do you need to use both API's for?

Comment: @LuisBosquez I came here because I want to feed Cosmos for MongoDB from PostgreSQL via mongo_fdw, and have use of the tools in the MongoDB ecosystem, but ideally have clients query it from JS on PHP-served pages with the REST API (no fancy server-side stuff, this is to get regional autosuggest and avoid our remote servers on another continent). Not sure yet if the keys mentioned below are required for that (I'm new to the platform), but relevant pages seem to imply that REST requires the SQL API and so the NoSQL flavour/kind.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use both the MongoDB API and the DocumentDB/Sql API in the same CosmosDB account by doing the following (this likely also works for CosmosDB accounts setup with Gremlin and Table APIs, but I haven't yet tried them yet.):

First, create a new CosmosDB account using the MongoDB API.  Once this new CosmosDB account is provisioned, you won't be able to find the "Keys" blade as you can with a CosmosDB account that has been configured with the DocumentDB/Sql API.

To get the Keys which you need to connect your client to the DocumentDB/Sql api, run the following [Azure CLI Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/cosmosdb):

```
az cosmosdb list-keys --name "<your cosmosdb account name>" --resource-group "<name of resource group your cosmosdb lives in>"
```

Now, you can use one of these keys in whatever client API (.Net, Python, etc.) that you are using, and do DocumentDB/Sql queries against your CosmosDB even though it was only configured to use the MongoDB api.

If your client API requires a "Connection String" instead of just a key, then edit the normal connection string to include this key in the "AccountKey" section of the string.

Answer (score 2):

> As with soo many other limitations of the Azure Portal, I'm hoping that there is a way to configure the new CosmosDB to use multiple APIs using PowerShell or the Azuzre cli.

AFAIK, Azure Cosmos DB supports multiple data models (key-value, documents, graphs, and columnar) for now. And each data models have the related APIs for accessing data including [MongoDB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-protocol-mongodb), [DocumentDB SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-introduction), [Gremlin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/graph-introduction) (preview), and [Azure Tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table-introduction) (preview).

When you creating an Azure Cosmos DB database account, you need to choose the data model with the related API (the type of your Azure Cosmos DB database account).

As [Create an Azure Cosmos DB account using the Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-automation-resource-manager-cli#a-idcreate-documentdb-account-clia-create-an-azure-cosmos-db-database-account) states about the `kind` parameter for creating database account:

> The type of Azure Cosmos DB database account to create.
>
> Allowed values: **GlobalDocumentDB**, **MongoDB**, Parse.
>
> **Default: GlobalDocumentDB**.

> Is there a way to add additional APIs to my CosmosDB instance? If not, will there be a way to do this in the future?

As I known, there is no approach for you to achieve it. Additionally, you could add your feedback [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db).

Answer (score 2):

The answer here is not valid anymore, No. While it might be technically possible. You have to stick to the one that you chose when creating the database.

The only combination possible are Gremlin and SQL API. Read from here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/faq#can-i-use-multiple-apis-to-access-my-data